# How to make backticks work in a HERE doc?

Tags: solaris, heredoc

I have a script2:

```
# This is script2 that is called by script1.    
CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS=`ps -ef | grep java | grep $TOMCAT_USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "---> $CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS"
```

and I call script2 in script1:

```
ssh $user@$server 'bash -s' < script2
```

It works fine. But I'm having trouble make the backtick work in a HERE document:

```
ssh $user@$server 'bash -s' <<EOF
     CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS=`ps -ef | grep java | grep $TOMCAT_USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`
     echo "---> $CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS"
EOF
```

(If I don't assign it to a variable and just print it out it works fine, but when I try to assign it to CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS variable using backticks, it doesn't work.)

How can I make this work?

Thanks,

===============================================================================

I could make it work the following way. There are lots of escaping involved:

```
ssh $user@$server 'bash -s' <<EOF
        CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS="\`ps -ef | grep java | grep $TOMCAT_USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'\`"
        echo "---> \$CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS"
EFO
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is reasonable to escape, because you want to transfer the '$' to remote site.  You seems make a typo on your last result.  I tried to type here again

```
TOMCATE_USER=foo
ssh $user@$server 'bash -s' <<EOF
CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS="\`ps -ef | grep java | grep $TOMCAT_USER | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'\`"
echo "---> \$CURRENT_TOMCAT_PROCESS"
EOF
```